# Web Site call to asp.net web api - image upload unsuccessful

Tags: c#, iis

**Question**

What timeout or setting do I need to change?

**Overview** showing experiments A-E
[image: Overview]

**Summary**

I have a website that makes an xhr api call to an asp.net web api site. It is uploading an image. It sends the image as a json object with a Base64Content property. The bytes are base64 encoded and automatically decoded by the web api site.

I have my web project set up in visual Studio with debugging, I also can build it and run it from IIS.

**What I've Tried**

**A**. If I test the api call to the web api rest site with Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger, it succeeds. What this means is, if the request successfully arrives at the web api server, it will succeed. All the back end code is good.

**B**. When it fails, Chrome debugger puts the raw request into the debugger tools. I can take that raw request, copy / paste it into Fiddler and it works. The ajax part of the website responsible for generating the request is all good (the request is formed correctly by the ajax code).

**C**. If I run my website in debug in Visual Studio with IIS Express, I do not have the issue. It only occurs in IIS. The entire `web.config` is identical.

**D**. If I test it through the web page itself (using Chrome) hitting IIS, It succeeds with a 500kb file but fails with a 1 meg file.

**E**. When it fails, there is no record whatsoever of this request arriving at the web api server. I've got full tracing on and nothing is showing up.

When it fails, it always fails at 5 seconds, regardless of the file size. Therefore, I conclude that it is not the file size that is causing the failure but rather any upload that takes longer than 5 seconds.

**My Settings**

I can't find any setting that I need to change that I have not already changed.

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"  />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" 
                 maxRequestLength="2097152" 
                 delayNotificationTimeout="360" 
                 executionTimeout="360"
                 defaultRegexMatchTimeout="360"
                 />
  </system.web>
```

**Request Log**

```
491472: URL_REQUEST
http://tmorrow-12v.hs.com/HS.REST.HomeownerPortal/api/tickets/281/images
Start Time: 2015-10-20 18:51:35.464

t=2876 [st=   0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=4996]
t=2876 [st=   0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=14]
t=2890 [st=  14]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=4982]
                    --> load_flags = 73986 (BYPASS_CACHE | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                    --> method = "POST"
                    --> priority = "LOW"
                    --> upload_id = "0"
                    --> url = "http://tmorrow-12v.hs.com/HS.REST.HomeownerPortal/api/tickets/281/images"
t=2890 [st=  14]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=1]
t=2891 [st=  15]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=2891 [st=  15]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=2891 [st=  15]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=2891 [st=  15]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
                        --> source_dependency = 491473 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=2892 [st=  16]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                        --> source_dependency = 491473 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=2892 [st=  16]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=2892 [st=  16]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=4980]
t=2892 [st=  16]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                        --> POST /HS.REST.HomeownerPortal/api/tickets/281/images HTTP/1.1
                            Host: tmorrow-12v.hs.com
                            Connection: keep-alive
                            Content-Length: 2632959
                            Pragma: no-cache
                            Cache-Control: no-cache
                            Authorization: Basic [52 bytes were stripped]
                            Origin: http://tmorrow-12v.hs.com
                            HSHO-Cookie: UserProfile=userid=31&username=tmorrow%40hyphensolutions.com&appguid=a967da12-2965-4b23-921b-ed8a386649f4&buildproappguid=0b43e124-7755-4194-a441-1836f8e6db48&loginexpiration=10%2f21%2f2015+12%3a00%3a00+AM&Expires=10%2f21%2f2015+12%3a00%3a00+AM&reqver
                            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
                            Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
                            Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
                            Referer: http://tmorrow-12v.hs.com/homeownerportal/
                            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
                            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
                            Cookie: [38 bytes were stripped]
t=2892 [st=  16]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_BODY
                        --> did_merge = false
                        --> is_chunked = false
                        --> length = 2632959
t=7872 [st=4996]        CANCELLED
t=7872 [st=4996]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                    --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=7872 [st=4996]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=7872 [st=4996] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Comment: Did you try adding timeout for ajax call? If you are using JQuery ajax function then error handler may throw some light on whats causing failure.

Comment: @PankajKapare, Thank you. I'm using $http in AngularJS. The object passed to the failure block is null. The client code is not using a time out. When it runs in IIS Express, it works OK so there must not be any Angular time out in effect (or so I reason). Anyway, I tried the `timeout` for `$http`, and set it to 3000 (3 seconds), just to see what it would do. It had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, uh, yeah. After 3 days of debugging, I found out:

The original developers had used this code to add an http interceptor to the client side logic, and I didn't think along the lines of a request filter and didn't search my project for "5000". When I saw `$http` wasn't using a `timeout` parameter, I assumed there was not one.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('timeoutHttpIntercept', function () {
    //this adds a timeout to every AJAX request
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
        config.timeout = 5000;
        return config;
      }
    };
  });
```

To fix it I just changed the value from 5000 to 60000. I didn't need any special values in the web.config for the rest api server.

The web server needed these settings in the web.config:

```xml
 <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"  />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
```